# What's the name of this Chinese/Japanese video game console

Tags: hardware-identification

This is a Chinese/Japanese video game console but I am not quite sure what it is. Does anyone recognise it?

[image: Picture of game console]

Comment: I hope it's not the Nintendo NX. scnr.

Comment: it is Nintento NX

Answer (score 14):

This is the CoolBoy FC-POCKET, which is basically a portable knock-off of the Famicom/NES.

More details in this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/47Hu7avkNuQ) or on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CoolBoy-FCPOCKET-Classic-8-bit-Game-Handheld-Console-build-in-472-games-free-128-in-1/32452888601.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.196.9NzriU) and [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CABGIOI).

Comment: That's portable?

Comment: @TimmyJim judging from the size of the plug on the top I'd say it's probably a little bigger than a Gameboy Advance, and that's pretty portable :-)

Comment: It looks deceivably bigger from the picture but I suppose you're right.